# 3D Cursor ~ right click to move it around? ver 2.8

Tags: workflow

So I have finally started using 2.8 beta. And of course there are a few things different.

I move the 3D cursor constantly = as much as I select and move objects. In 2.79b I switched mouse buttons so LEFT selected and RIGHT moved the cursor.

But in 2.8 they have made left select (fine), and now right brings up an "object context menu" that I would never in a million years use. Why? So now if I want to move the cursor I have to go ALL THE WAY up to the top left and click on the cursor icon in the tools list. Then I can move it. To go back to moving objects I have to go BACK UP THERE again.

This has to be a horrible mistake, or something I can't find in preferences to change. I've noticed that I can SHIFT-RIGHT click and move the cursor (after experimenting)... but that still adds an unreasonable action to workflow.

I want the RIGHT mouse button to move the 3D cursor like it used to. Is that possible? I want the silly menu to stop coming up when I right click because it is useless ~ if I really need it, it's under the object pull down menu.

And a side note - Z now opens a directional menu for some reason. I used to be able to quickly toggle wireframe and solid.

And 'A' to select and deselect now wants me to double tap or ALT-A.

I'm guessing the dev team has attempted to make things easier for folks that are perhaps new to modeling. But they have added time consuming steps to an otherwise smooth operation. I hope they implement an option to use 'classic setup' routines under preferences.

And I don't intend to be complaining - but I am complaining. Dang it.

I use a Corsair Scimitar mouse with 10 programmable buttons on the side. And I can reprogram one (or even the right mouse) to add in the SHIFT if I want to. And I probably will. But I am still wondering if there isn't a way for the software to do it that I am missing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It should be old news by now, but you can revert to Blender 2.7x shortcuts and usability at any point.

In the menu, go to "Edit- Preferences", select "Keymap" and you find all the changes in one place.

In the upper row, you find the presets, where you can find a Blender 2.7x preset. Don't forget to hit "Save Preferences", before closing the window.

[image: revert inputs to Blender 2.7x]

Depending on how proficient you are with Blender in general, this could also backfire, if you watch tutorials that are created using the new keymap. You definitely want to know your way around in Blender to be able to follow those.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the exact answer. I would like to add a little information for anyone else that may view this in the same regards. The option under Keymap->Blender 27X has immediate effect for things like 'A' selection and 'Z' wireframe toggle... However to also change the click-ability of the mouse to move the 3D Cursor you have to further open the 3D View pull-down menu and change the 'Set 3D Cursor' mapping to ''Right Mouse" - do this by clicking on the existing setting, then click the mouse button you wish to assign the action to. Thanks again!

Comment: @atomkey -  If this answer solves your problem, please consider to [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: metaphor_set - I already tried to accept it. StackExchange reports I don't have enough reputation to do so. When I am able I promise to return and give you a +1 for the time you took for me. It tells me my action was recorded but the change isn't visible. I think that is sorta silly but I understand the reasoning for it. If you have an alternative that I am missing please advise and I will follow suit.